# Get the unique items for all array - Handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

With the code that I used I only partially succeeded.
Is it possible to have a single item when the value is equal for all array? (i.e. "citta": "Roma").

Now i have the following result: - Roma - Napoli- Roma - Roma

I'd like to have the following result: - Roma - Napoli. I don't want repeat "Roma".

Can anyone help me? Thank you

```
{
    "test": [
    {
        "33": [
        {
          "name": "Antonio",
          "citta": "Roma",
          "orari":  "2020-01-11T10:50:00.000+01:00"
      },
            {
          "name": "Federico",
          "citta": "Roma"

      }
      ]
    },
      {
        "34": [
        {
           "name": "Antonio",
          "citta": "Napoli"

      }
      ]
    },
     { "36": [
        {
           "name": "Antonio",
          "citta": "Roma"

      }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>
 {{#each test}} <ul> <li>{{#each this}}{{#eachUnique this}} - {{citta}}{{/eachUnique}}  {{/each}}</li> </ul> {{/each}} 
</div>
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
<script>
var seasons_data_url = "working-data-file.json";
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON(seasons_data_url,
    function (data) {
      var mysource = $('#sourceTemplate').html();
      var mytemplate = Handlebars.compile(mysource);
      var myresult = mytemplate(data)
      $('#resultPlaceholder').html(myresult);
  });
});
  Handlebars.registerHelper('eachUnique', function(array, options) {
  // this is used for the lookup
  var  dupCheck = {};
  // template buffer
  var buffer = '';
  for( var i=0; i< array.length; i++){
    var entry = array[i];
    var uniqueKey = entry.IP + entry.What + entry.When + entry.How;
    // check if the entry has been added already
    if(!dupCheck[uniqueKey]){
      // here there are only unique values
      dupCheck[uniqueKey] = true;
      // add this in the template
      buffer += options.fn(entry);
    }
  }
  // return the template compiled
  return buffer;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of way to achieve a unique array.

**Vanilla JavaScript**

With vanilla JavaScript you can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
  var foo = new Set();
  test.forEach(item => foo.add(item.citta));
  return Array.from(foo);
```

Even better would be to pass the non-unique array itself to the set contractor and it will create the unique set out of that array

```
  return Array.from(new Set(test.map(item => item.citta)));
```

**Using Lodash.js**

Lodash.js has a [`uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniq) function.
I would also recommand using [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) and [`chain`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chain)

```js
  return _.chain(test)
    .map(item => item.citta)
    .uniq()
    .value();
```

**A solution to your example would be:**

You basically want to iterate over you object and create a `Set` out of it to include your `citta` out of each underlying object,
Then you want to add an `Array` made by this `Set` to your `context` and change your `#each` to use that array.

Here is a code modification that solves the problem using the example you've provided in the comments.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>
 {{#each cittas}} <ul> <li>{{this}}</li> </ul> {{/each}} 
</div>
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@7.2.0/dist/js/autoComplete.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var context = {
    "test": [
    {
        "33": [
        {
          "name": "Antonio",
          "citta": "Roma",
          "orari":  "2020-01-11T10:50:00.000+01:00"
      },
            {
          "name": "Federico",
          "citta": "Roma",
          "orari":  "2020-01-11T12:50:00.000+01:00"
      }
      ]
    },
      {
        "34": [
        {
           "name": "Antonio",
          "citta": "Napoli",
          "orari":  "2020-01-11T10:50:00.000+01:00"
      }
      ]
    },
        {
        "35": [
        {
           "name": "Antonio",
          "citta": "Roma",
          "orari":  "2020-01-11T10:50:00.000+01:00"
      }
      ]
    },
     { "36": [
        {
           "name": "Antonio",
          "citta": "Roma",
          "orari":  "2020-01-11T10:50:00.000+01:00"
      }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
context.cittas = Array.from(context.test.reduce((foo, item) => {
  Object.values(item).forEach(a => {
    a.forEach(b => {
      foo.add(b.citta);
    });
  });
  return foo;
}, new Set()))
  var source = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
  Handlebars.registerHelper('eachUnique', function(array, options) {
  // this is used for the lookup
  var  dupCheck = {};
  // template buffer
  var buffer = '';
  for( var i=0; i< array.length; i++){
    var entry = array[i];
    var uniqueKey = entry.IP + entry.What + entry.When + entry.How;
    // check if the entry has been added already
    if(!dupCheck[uniqueKey]){
      // here there are only unique values
      dupCheck[uniqueKey] = true;
      // add this in the template
      buffer += options.fn(entry);
    }
  }
  // return the template compiled
  return buffer;
});

</script>
```

Comment: should I use one of the two snippet (vanilla or lodash)?

Comment: If you have lodash in your project I would go with it. I wouldn't add lodash to the project just for this issue.

Comment: I added the following code but it doesn't work

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@7.2.0/dist/js/autoComplete.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var foo = new Set();
  test.forEach(item => foo.add(item.citta));
 return Array.from(new Set(test.map(item => item.citta)));
    
</script>

Comment: Can you please provide a working example? using jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Comment: You have a problem with your test object. its an array of object that have an id as a key and an array of items. Why not change it to be just an object where id is the key and array of items instead of the main array? that way it will be easier to iterate.

Comment: i have an external json data that i can't change. isn't there a solution?

Comment: if I want to call data from external json file? is it possible?
before in my code there was var seasons_data_url = "working-data-file.json";

Comment: Isn’t possible? I hope you can help me. Thank you an advance